# How can I use MVC views that are in a seperate project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodellocator

At work, I have a fairly old web app that runs on Web Forms.  It's written in VB .NET.

I am trying to move away from VB.NET as the main language for obvious reasons, so I have started another project in the solution with MVC and C# as the language.

I can't just add MVC to the same project because I can't mix languages in the same project (and even if I could I'm not sure I would want to).  My plan is to have the main web project depend on the MVC project, but at launch, have the main project bootstrap the MVC stuff, set up the routes, and route any "not found" route in the MVC project into the Web Forms project.

I know I can compile my Razor views into code, but this means when I make changes in the views and save them as the app is running, these changes aren't reflected on the running web service.  I have to rebuild to see changes which I don't want to do over and over again.

Based on this, I seem to be required to create a new view locator for the view engine, and then specify where to look for the views.  The only issue is that the new MVC project runs in a folder next to the main project, so I can't use a relative path that goes *beyond* the root of the original project (If I'm in the old project, I can't just make the view location `~/../../newProject/Views/{1}/Partials/{0}.cshtml` because this goes above the root for the old project)

So, how can I create a view locator that will locate the views in a seperate project?

Comment: about the changes on your pages and their "appearance" on your running webserver, that's why we usually set up an automated continuous deployment pipeline  for websites. This may seems  heavy, but that's the way it's done.

Comment: @Pac0 I believe you may have mis-read the question - I'm saying "Web Forms" not "Win Forms".  Web forms predates MVC, its a different pattern.  Picture two projects in a solution, one is Web Forms, the other is MVC.  I just want to use controllers and views from the MVC project in the Web Forms project.

Comment: Indeed, I read wrongly Winforms, you are right. I'll delete the first comment.

Comment: also removed the comment about viewmodels since you edited the question

Comment: But you were right about my spurious use of "view model locator" :).  It's not the view models I want to locate, its the physical view files (the cshtml files).

Comment: You can copy them to the `/bin` dir on build, right click the views.

Comment: @Charles yes but I can't update them as the app is running in the MVC project and see those updates.  The copy will only run once when the app is built.  It won't re-copy when I update the views in the MVC project without a stop and start, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I'd just write a script to copy them to a nice location. Maybe make a separate project for that. If you don't want to press a button to copy you can even use a `FileSystemWatcher`. But the general consens it to not reuse views too much.

Comment: Initially I had an npm script to do this but I'd like to not introduce another dependency for another developer to have to remember every time to start the script when they are doing development.  I'm making a console app to copy views now using `FileSystemWatcher`. It just seems heavy handed.

Comment: I can't believe that nobody has an answer for this. I'm writing an awful directory sync thing to make this work.